# Should I store different size's image for different Image component size to improve performance?

Tags: android, html, ios, performance, react-native

I am working in react native with Image component and I have to use same image at multiple locations with different size. Like user profile image at:

1. In profile section, with a large circle of about half the device height - 600x600px,
2. In others contact section in the list of the contacts as thumbnail image - 80x80px,
3. In chatting section, sending an image to other user, image message will appear in a small box -200x200px.

My concern is should I create a small exact image size crop/compressed version for each sizes above or I must use the original size image like 1000x1000 everywhere, irrespective of the Image component size

1. If I create a crop version of each image of perfect size than a lot of memory will be used on device and
2. If I use the original image (downloaded off-course) then react-native Image component may need to do lot of efforts to crop it to perfect size. This may leads to performance issue.

Please help with the correct approach.

Comment: There is no "correct" approach.  It's going to be based entirely on what you consider a reasonable tradeoff between complexity, performance and amount of data transferred.

Comment: What is your preference between the 2 above approaches?

Comment: The one that most effectively meets my specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since react native follows the pattern of the web so it is smart enough to compress the image size to make it to the size of the Image component you are using, it may take some time for compressing the size, which seems a more viable solution rather than creating a compressed copy by yourself for each asset. Assets may keep on changing so it will be difficult to track.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put logic on the server side. When you tried to upload an image then the server will resize the image in the necessary resolution which you need to use in application along with Original.

You need to render a particular image from the server on a particular screen. For downloading an image you can use [FastImage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image).